# Search operators in the app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, search

The search operators (`or`, `and`, `answers: x..y`, `hascode:true/false`, etc.) don't work in the Stack Exchange Android app. Is this intended or not (maybe there is a bug or something)?

If not, I think it should be added.

Comment: `answers:x..y` and `hascode:true` do work on v1.0.89 (make sure there's no space), but only if the sorting is *not* set to "Relevant". Still seems a bug though.